# What is this in powershell?

Tags: powershell

At the top of a powershell file I see this. Is this an anonymous object, and how do I access `$foo`?

```
properties {

  $foo = "bar"
}
```

Comment: `properties` isn't a powershell keyword... maybe is a custom function called from the script?

Comment: It is a command `properties` that takes an argument which is a scriptblock. This is probably a build script for `psake`.

Comment: @Roman, yes it is a `psake` build script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are looking at looks like its using the psake framework

[Psake Framework Properties](https://github.com/psake/psake/wiki/How-can-I-override-a-property-defined-in-my-psake-script?)